# Any way to use variables in property/rule names?

Tags: css, less

Is there any way to use variable in a property or rule name i.e:

```
.foo {
   @dir: right;
   border-{@dir}: 2px;
}
```

Comment: That's a *property name*, not a rule name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your post with Sass, so here's how you'd do it with the SCSS syntax:

```
.foo {
   $dir: right;
   border-#{$dir}: 2px;
}
```

I verified this as working on [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, actually my code will work with slight modification, placing `@` before `}`.

```
@dir: right;
.foo-@{dir} {
  border-@{dir}: 2px;
}
```